# SQL merge two queries with multiple rows in one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made two separate requests on a view, each result has several lines.
You can see that one of the two columns of the result is the same.

I would like to know how to merge the two queries to obtain a single table with the 3 columns, even if some results are NULL.
the aim being to group several results in order to obtain a general progress result.

Thanks.

first query

```
SELECT appui.pa, COUNT(appui.gid) AS appui_non_lance

FROM genie_civil.v_appui appui

JOIN suivi.v_contour_aerien aer ON aer.id = appui.contour_etude

WHERE num_appui LIKE 'E%'

AND etat_appui != 'Non utilisé'

AND type_travaux != 'artère neuve'

AND avancement_etude_app = 'non renseigné'

AND date_envoi_pv IS NULL

AND date_retour_pv IS NULL

AND etat_pv = '--Non Renseigné--'

AND aer.date_depot_erdf IS NULL

AND aer.etat_etude_erdf = 'NC'

AND aer.etat_affaire IS NULL

AND date_com IS NULL

AND valid_com IS NULL

--AND date_envoi_executant_app IS NULL

AND date_retour_tvx_appui IS NULL

AND aer.etat_aat = '--Non renseigné--'

AND date_tfx IS NULL

AND valid_tfx IS NULL

AND aer.date_envoi_d2 IS NULL

GROUP BY appui.pa;
```

second query

```
 SELECT appui.pa, COUNT(appui.gid) AS appui_en_releve

FROM genie_civil.v_appui appui

JOIN suivi.v_contour_aerien aer ON aer.id = appui.contour_etude

WHERE num_appui LIKE 'E%'

AND etat_appui != 'Non utilisé'

AND avancement_etude_app IN('à relever', 'en cours relevé', 'à contrôler relevé')

AND date_envoi_pv IS NULL

AND date_retour_pv IS NULL

AND etat_pv = '--Non Renseigné--'

AND date_com IS NULL

AND valid_com IS NULL

--AND date_envoi_executant_app IS NULL

AND date_retour_tvx_appui IS NULL

AND aer.date_depot_erdf IS NULL

AND aer.etat_etude_erdf ='NC'

AND aer.etat_affaire IS NULL

AND aer.etat_aat = '--Non renseigné--'

AND date_tfx IS NULL

AND valid_tfx IS NULL

AND aer.date_envoi_d2 IS NULL

GROUP BY appui.pa;
```

Comment: It looks like the tables/joins and grouping are the same across both the queries. You can write `where  (<conditions for result 1>) or (<conditions for result 2>)`. Makes sure to use parentheses.

Comment: the filters are almost identical, but not exactly, the result will have a different purpose. That's why you need a column for each result, thank you.

Comment: So you're talking about combining the results horizontally rather than vertically (as with `UNION`)? `with q1 as (<query1>), q2 as (<query2>) select * from q1 full outer join q2 on q2.? = q1.?`

Comment: Since the queries are basically the same it makes more sense to use a conditional aggregation. See my answer below.

Comment: exact, I have a dozen requests almost identical to this one, only the filters are different, the result must be used to manipulate layers on Qgis

Comment: Psycho33200, then follow the pattern I used in my answer. Putting shared filters in the `where` clause might benefit query performance. Otherwise put everything inside the `case` various expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `UNION ALL`. More information is in the Postgres documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/queries-union.html

Comment: thanks, i have test UNION ALL but the result table have only the first SELECT.
I may have done badly the query.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT appui.pa, COUNT(appui.gid) AS appui_non_lance 
FROM genie_civil.v_appui appui
JOIN suivi.v_contour_aerien aer ON aer.id = appui.contour_etude
WHERE num_appui LIKE 'E%'
AND etat_appui != 'Non utilisé' AND type_travaux != 'artère neuve' AND avancement_etude_app = 'non renseigné'
AND date_envoi_pv IS NULL AND date_retour_pv IS NULL AND etat_pv = '--Non Renseigné--'
AND aer.date_depot_erdf IS NULL AND aer.etat_etude_erdf = 'NC' AND aer.etat_affaire IS NULL
AND date_com IS NULL AND valid_com IS NULL
--AND date_envoi_executant_app IS NULL
AND date_retour_tvx_appui IS NULL AND aer.etat_aat = '--Non renseigné--' AND date_tfx IS NULL
AND valid_tfx IS NULL AND aer.date_envoi_d2 IS NULL 
GROUP BY appui.pa

UNION ALL

SELECT appui.pa, COUNT(appui.gid) AS appui_en_releve FROM genie_civil.v_appui appui
JOIN suivi.v_contour_aerien aer ON aer.id = appui.contour_etude
WHERE num_appui LIKE 'E%' 
AND etat_appui != 'Non utilisé' AND avancement_etude_app IN('à relever', 'en cours relevé', 'à contrôler relevé')
AND date_envoi_pv IS NULL AND date_retour_pv IS NULL AND etat_pv = '--Non Renseigné--' AND date_com IS NULL
AND valid_com IS NULL 
--AND date_envoi_executant_app IS NULL
AND date_retour_tvx_appui IS NULL AND aer.date_depot_erdf IS NULL AND aer.etat_etude_erdf ='NC'
AND aer.etat_affaire IS NULL AND aer.etat_aat = '--Non renseigné--'  AND date_tfx IS NULL 
AND valid_tfx IS NULL AND aer.date_envoi_d2 IS NULL
GROUP BY appui.pa;
```

Comment: thanks, i'm testing it tomorrow at work.
I only have access to the database at work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking to have two separate counts. This approach is best because you only scan the table once. I've moved the conditions common to both of the queries into the `where` clause while the others are part of the respective `case` expressions.

```
SELECT appui.pa,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN
            type_travaux != 'artère neuve'
        AND avancement_etude_app = 'non renseigné'
        AND aer.date_depot_erdf IS NULL
        AND aer.etat_etude_erdf = 'NC'
    THEN 1 END) AS appui_non_lance,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN
            etat_appui != 'Non utilisé'
        AND avancement_etude_app IN ('à relever', 'en cours relevé', 'à contrôler relevé')
    THEN 1 END) AS appui_en_releve
FROM genie_civil.v_appui appui INNER JOIN suivi.v_contour_aerien aer
    ON aer.id = appui.contour_etude
WHERE
        num_appui LIKE 'E%'
    AND etat_appui != 'Non utilisé'
    AND etat_pv = '--Non Renseigné--'
    AND date_envoi_pv IS NULL
    AND date_retour_pv IS NULL
    AND aer.etat_affaire IS NULL
    AND date_com IS NULL
    AND valid_com IS NULL
    --AND date_envoi_executant_app IS NULL
    AND aer.etat_aat = '--Non renseigné--'
    AND date_tfx IS NULL
    AND date_retour_tvx_appui IS NULL
    AND valid_tfx IS NULL
    AND aer.date_envoi_d2 IS NULL
GROUP BY appui.pa;
```